# unable to load from timestamp json field to synapse data lake table timestamp column

Tags: json, timestamp, azure-synapse

I've been trying and trying in Azure Synapse Studio to load my json data from ADLS to an Azure data lake table, and the String and Int columns load fine, but not the Timestamp column. It previews as NULL in the data flow output stream, if I let the pipeline run it writes it back out to ADLS as an empty string, and if I then query the table it shows up as (NULL). If I change the column data type to String it works fine, so it's specific to the timestamp datatype.

A sample JSON file looks like:

```
[{
    "mold_id": "sensor1",
    "time_utc": "2022-04-08T15:34:16Z",
    "temperature": 80
}, {
    "mold_id": "sensor1",
    "time_utc": "2022-04-10T15:34:16Z",
    "temperature": 85
}]
```

and the column is defined as "Data type: timestamp" and "Format/Length: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: BTW, I can also get it to work if the column is defined as "Data type: date" and "Format/Length: YYYY-MM-DD", and changing the data accordingly, but still not for "timestamp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure synapse does not support the `timestamp` datatype. It works when the column is defined as `date` (yyyy-mm-dd) because it is a supported type. However, when you have a timestamp column, you can use cast the column to `datetime` type which is supported by azure synapse.

There are several other date and time datatypes that are supported by Azure synapse analytics. You can refer to the following link to know more about these types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

The datatype that might work for you would be `datetime` or `datetime2`. You can refer to the following links to know more about these datatypes.

datetime:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

datetime2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Here is a document which references the unsupported datatypes (Refer section- Workarounds for unsupported datatypes).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-data-types